# Gradle flavors with small code differences

Tags: android, gradle, versions

I have an application which has a free and a paid flavor.  I am starting to add additional features to the paid version.  To this point, the flavor differences have been handled either by a boolean in the build gradle or a couple of different layouts in the flavor folders.  The layout differences up to this point existed because advertising code was embedded in the layout xml. Going forward some of these will have unique items/content but most of the new stuff will have its own layouts.

Almost all the additional features will reside in specific classes for the paid flavor. However, I'm a bit perplexed with what to do with a few of my activity classes which begin with a menu of user choices and are for all intents common to both flavors.  It seems there is no way, for instance, to use a click listener which references an R.id in one flavor of the layout but not the other.  Thus the activity itself must be maintained in two versions.

It seems excessive and cumbersome to maintain two flavors of activity code just to deal with a few non-common lines.  I was thinking the best way to handle my very specific instance is to make sure both layouts have all the R.id's necessary for the activity and to hide the unused ones. Not ideal, but less cumbersome than maintaining two versions of the activity.

Is there a better way to handle this in general?

Comment: I see your dilemma...one suggestion might be rather than maintaining separate activity code, just maintain separate clicklistener classes. Or, if there's enough difference in the activities, stick the common code in an Activity class under the main flavor, and have the other flavors subclass from that main flavor Activity an override onClick in each etc.

Comment: When I faced this issue I prefered an easy solution: create a id_store.xml layout, that is never referenced in the code. It contains any id that is not declared in this flavour. This way the R reference the id, and I check any findViewById() with a if(null)